# how to get access $geowithin after populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

this is the seller's data

```
{
        "orderStatus": "active",
        "_id": "5f364413bb0786070d467eee",
        "userid": {
            "usertype": "seller",
            "_id": "5f36095b2046a5034afdaa71",
            "name": "chinnu",
            "email": "chinnu@gmail.com",
            "phonenumber": "9618222516",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "address": {
            "location": {
                "coordinates": [
                    78.44785,
                    17.84677
                ],
                "type": "Point",
                "city": "Toopran"
            },
            "_id": "5f360a142046a5034afdaa72",
            "userid": "5f36095b2046a5034afdaa71",
            "hno": "7-3/1",
            "village": "toopran",
            "street": "near gandhi statue",
            "mandal": "toopran",
            "district": "medak",
            "state": "telangana",
            "pincode": "502334",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "postedDate": "14/08/2020",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

so I (buyer) want to populate and I want to access location object in address filed and get users in the range of 100 km, but I am getting empty array.

I am able to access the ranged users if the table contains direct location property with longitude and latitude.

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
         const lat = req.query.latitude;
         const lon = req.query.longitude;
        const radius = 100 / 6378;
        // console.log(radius)
        const foundUsers = await sellerData
          .find({
            orderStatus: "active",
            location: {
              $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[78.363151, 17.912214], radius] },
            },
          })
          .populate([
            {
              path: "userid",
              model: "seller_user_table",
              select: "-soldHistory",
            },
            { path: "address", model: "address" },
          ]);
        res.status(200).json(foundUsers)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ success : false , error : error.message })
  }
});
```

this is the schema

```
const mongoose =  require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const seller_table_data_schema = Schema({
  userid: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "seller_user_table",
    required: true,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  scarpType : {
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  address: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "address",
    required: true,
  },
  postedDate: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  orderStatus: {
    type: String,
    default: "active",
  },
});

const seller_table_data = mongoose.model("seller_table_data", seller_table_data_schema);

module.exports = seller_table_data;
```

This is the address schema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const geocoder = require('../utils/geocoder')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const address_Schema = Schema({
        userid : {
            type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'seller_user_table'
        },
        hno : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        village : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        street : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        mandal : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        district : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        state : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        pincode : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        location : {
            type : {
                type : String
            },
            coordinates : {
                type : [Number]
            },
            city : String
        }
})

address_Schema.pre('save',async function(next){
    const address_data = `${this.hno},${this.village},${this.mandal},${this.district},${this.state},${this.pincode}`;
    
    const loc = await geocoder.geocode(address_data)
    console.log(loc)
    this.location = {
        type : 'Point',
        coordinates : [loc[0].longitude,loc[0].latitude],
        city : loc[0].city
    };

    next()
})


const address = mongoose.model("address", address_Schema);

module.exports = address;
```

Comment: can you help how to do that with my code please

Comment: i had already tried this "address.location": {  also it is not working

Comment: ok will check if possible with populate or not, otherwise you need to move to aggregate(), will update you.

Comment: can you add your schemas in your question..

Comment: bro check i have added schema

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is possible with populate method or not, but you can try [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html),

```
const radius = 100 / 6378;
const foundUsers = await sellerData.aggregate([

  // Match conditions
  { $match: { orderStatus: "active" } },

  // Join with 'seller_user_table' collection 
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "seller_user_table",
      localField: "userid",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "userid"
    }
  },

  // deconstruct userId because by default lookup will return an array
  { $unwind: { path: "$userid" } },

  // join address collection
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "address",
      localField: "address",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "address"
    }
  },

  // deconstruct address because by default lookup will return an array
  { $unwind: { path: "$address" } },

  // match condition for address location
  {
    $match: {
      "address.location": {
        $geoWithin: {
          $centerSphere: [
            [78.363151, 17.912214],
            radius
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X9enxrVfKM_)

Comment: Bro no luck , same result i am getting empty array check i have added address schema also in the question

Comment: have you check playground link, is that ok? why its working?

Comment: in the playground section, it is working but in my code, it is not working giving empty array

Comment: can you try to change the radius number, and try to execute after removing last pipeline `$match`, let me know what happens

Comment: i have removed `$match` still i am getting same empty array

Comment: so there must be some mistake on field name or while first match or lookup, just compare with your collection and correct it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219823/discussion-between-turivishal-and-ram-sai).

Comment: You can chat in above link and reply to my last comment from chat it will notify me.